# In which file is the list of the installed modules saved?

Tags: 8

I am trying to synchronize some config data, and I'm getting the following error:

```
X depends on modules (examples here) that will not be installed after import.
```

Now I'm fine with adding the setting that they'll be enabled after synchronization, but I cannot for the life of me find any documentation or where in the config files this lives.

Does anyone have any information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `core.extension.yml`. Directory for configuration synchronization is set up in `settings.php` with variable `$config_directories`.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management) is the documentation, but it's not full.

Comment: Yep, this is right. Figured it out shortly after posting and going through all sorts of config files. Thank you for the link!